# How to install/ write delphi or object pascal code in VS Code

Tags: delphi, visual-studio-code, omnipascal

How do I code pascal in VS Code? How do I tell VS Code where to look for the compiler, because I have RAD Studio 10.3 installed. And, how do I compile a multi-file program?

I have managed to attain Omnipascal in VS Code for the syntax highlight, but not much else. Any additional help and information will be appreciated!

Comment: 99% sure that using VSCode will create more problems than solve. If you already have RAD Studio installed, better to use it as IDE.

Comment: Not a direct answer but since you have RAD Studio 10.3 installed, you don't nee VS Code. RAD Studio has his own IDE which is really very powerful not only to write object pascal code, but also to create the user interface incredibly quickly and manage multiple projects each having multiple files. Look at [Getting started with RAD Studio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney)/en/Getting_Started_with_RAD_Studio

Comment: The compilers in Delphi are called dcc32 (for Win32) and dcc64 (for Win64). There are others for other platforms. They are located in the bin subdirectory of your Delphi installation. I have no idea how to configure VSCode to use them, though. If you insist on doing that you are probably on our own as I know of no other Delphi developer who does this. Delphi itself uses msbuild, so the project's .proj file might give yo a clue.

Comment: Before v10.4, local professional developers had gone to VS Code (and demonstrated it) because they were having trouble with CodeInsight etc being very slow for a large project.  I understand it is much improved for them in 10.4.x versions with the LSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi comes with a very powerful and stable GUI, very low need for using Omnipascal and VS.
Find basic tutorial  here :

1. [Omnipascal run, compile ...](http://blog.omnipascal.com/omnipascal-0-13-0-load-project-compile-and-run/)
2. [Delphi Praxis
   Omnipascal](https://www.delphipraxis.net/187311-omnipascal-delphi-oder-freepascal-visual-studio-code-6.html)    (german only)

pick uo code sample  from 2.nd. link